# How to show text while the progressBar is loading and then to remove the text when loading has finish?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The main goal is to display a progressBar while the page is loading with some text and in the end when the page has loaded to remove the text. but the text is shown in the end after the page has loaded and instead I want the text to be shown on the start and to be removed in the end.

The html code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="loadbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class='progress' id="progress_div">
   <div class='bar' id='bar1'></div>
   <div class='percent' id='percent1'></div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="content">
     <h1>Loading map please wait...</h1>
   </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="progress_width" value="0">
```

the text in this line is show only when the bar and the page finished loading:

```
<h1>Loading map please wait...</h1>
```

but I want this text to be show on the start and then when the page has finished loading to remove the text.

The css:

```
body
{
  margin:0px auto;
  padding:0px;
  font-family:helvetica;
}
.progress 
{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
.bar 
{ 
  background-color: #819FF7; 
  width:0%; 
  height:5px; 
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.percent 
{ 
  position:absolute; 
  display:inline-block; 
  top:3px; 
  left:48%; 
}
#wrapper
{
  width:995px;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px auto;
  font-family:helvetica;
  text-align:center;
}
h1
{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:35px;
  margin-top:60px;
  color:#A9BCF5;
}
h1 p
{
  text-align:center;
  margin:0px;
  font-size:18px;
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:grey;
}
```

The javascript:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
      var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
      for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {
        set_ele(all[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  
  function check_element(ele) {
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var totalele = all.length;
    var per_inc = 100 / all.length;
  
    if ($(ele).on()) {
      var prog_width = per_inc + Number(document.getElementById("progress_width").value);
      document.getElementById("progress_width").value = prog_width;
      $("#bar1").animate({
        width: prog_width + "%"
      }, 10, function() {
        if (document.getElementById("bar1").style.width == "100%") {
          $(".progress").fadeOut("slow");
        }
      });
    } else {
      set_ele(ele);
    }
  }
  
  function set_ele(set_element) {
    check_element(set_element);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions. Here is one:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="loadbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class='progress' id="progress_div">
   <div class='bar' id='bar1'></div>
   <div class='percent' id='percent1'></div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="content">
     <h1 id="loading-message">Loading map please wait...</h1>
   </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="progress_width" value="0">
<div>
```

```
document.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
      var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
      for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {
        set_ele(all[i]);
      }
      $("#loading-message").remove();//this is what I added to remove it on readyState == "interactive".
    }
  }
```

Here is another:

```
<body onload="loaded();">
```

```
function loaded() {
  $("#loading-message").remove();
}
```

The first one waits until `readyState` is `"interactive"`. The second waits until the whole page has fully loaded.